# how make pointers to follow another pointer in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to write a program that uses Pointers and when I change the value of a pointer, the others follow that pointer; here is my code:

```
int * M1  =   new  int(1) ;
int * M2  =   new  int(2) ;
int * M3  =   new  int(3) ;
int * M4  =   new  int(4) ;
int * M5  =   new  int(5) ;

int * M6  =   new  int(6) ;
int * M7  =   new  int(7) ;
int * M8  =   new  int(8) ;
int * M9  =   new  int(9)  ;
int * M10  =  new  int(10) ;





M1 = M2  = M3  = M4  = M5;

M6 = M7  = M8  = M9  = M10;



*M5  = *M10;  //  now *M1 : *M5   is equal  *M10

*M10   = 120; //  this only changes  *M6  : *M10   but I want *M1 : *M5  changes too
```

how can I change whole *M1 : *M10  without using loop??

Comment: `M1 = M2  = M3  = M4  = M5;` -- You now have created a memory leak.  What's the reason for even attempting anything like this?  What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? This code is just plain weird to a C++ programmer to even do.

Comment: this is an example, I know how to avoid memory leak, I want to change data without using for loop

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Ok,  I want to create a tree,  each Node has a Parent  or Is a Parent ,

Comment: You don't create a tree this way.  There are tons of implementations in C++ that show proper creation of a tree, whether it is a BST, a B-Tree, a trie, etc.

Comment: When you do `i = j; j = 5;` it doesn't make i 5. Same with pointers. When you do `*pi = *pj; *pj = 5;` it doesn't make \*pj 5. *Unless* pj and pi point to the same variable.

Comment: All parents are pointers  And I what I want to do is  when I change A Parent, All Nodes that connected to it changes automatically their parents.

Comment: So you want M5 to be the parent of M4?

Comment: I want All pointers follow one pointer. Is this possible in c++?

Comment: @mohamadmahdi -- I suggest you create a legitimate tree first.  Then all of the things you are stating will become obvious as to how to accomplish them.  What you are doing is jumping right into the middle of some operation you want to do with a tree, and you yet have any code that builds a tree properly.  Once you have that code, then you can see how to manipulate the parents so that the tree can be properly pruned.

Comment: thank you very much for your answers. but can you please tell me  how can I Make All pointers to point at a same memory?

Comment: @mohamadmahdi `int M1; int *M2 = &M1; int *M2 = &M1;`

Comment: thank you again.im so so sorry,  if you have an array of pointers, for example std::vector<int *> , what is the fastest way to make themall to  follow one pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you're asking in the *way* you're asking it. Pointers are kind of like labels for memory locations, and moving one label doesn't change the location any of the other labels are pointing to. Let's visualize the starting state:

```
1 <- M1
2 <- M2
3 <- M3
4 <- M4
5 <- M5
6 <- M6
7 <- M7
8 <- M8
9 <- M9
10 <- M10
```

On the `M1 = M2 = M3 = M4 = M5` line, you're moving the first four pointers (just labels) to point where M5 is pointing at (call it location 5). Similarly for the next line, to point M6:M9 to where M10 is pointing at (call it location 10).

```
1 <- 
2 <- 
3 <- 
4 <- 
5 <- M1,M2,M3,M4,M5
6 <- 
7 <- 
8 <- 
9 <- 
10 <- M6,M7,M8,M9,M10
```

With your line `*M5 = *M10`, you change just the value at M5's location, location 5. The location of all the labels doesn't change.

```
1 <- 
2 <- 
3 <- 
4 <- 
10 <- M1,M2,M3,M4,M5
6 <- 
7 <- 
8 <- 
9 <- 
10 <- M6,M7,M8,M9,M10
```

Your last line does the same, for location 10:

```
1 <- 
2 <- 
3 <- 
4 <- 
10 <- M1,M2,M3,M4,M5
6 <- 
7 <- 
8 <- 
9 <- 
120 <- M6,M7,M8,M9,M10
```

If you want to move those labels again, you'll need to move them individually. They point to a location, but are each their own separate labels. The shortest way to do what you want from the end of your program is:

```cpp
M1 = M2 = M3 = M4 = M5 = M10;
```

```
1 <- 
2 <- 
3 <- 
4 <- 
10 <-
6 <- 
7 <- 
8 <- 
9 <- 
120 <- M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9,M10
```

If you want all of them to point at that last location by pointing them to M5's location, you can do that by modifying your code a little bit to move M5 first:

```cpp
int * M1  =   new  int(1) ;
int * M2  =   new  int(2) ;
int * M3  =   new  int(3) ;
int * M4  =   new  int(4) ;
int * M5  =   new  int(5) ;

int * M6  =   new  int(6) ;
int * M7  =   new  int(7) ;
int * M8  =   new  int(8) ;
int * M9  =   new  int(9)  ;
int * M10  =  new  int(10) ;


M5 = M10; // M5 now points to location 10


M1 = M2  = M3  = M4  = M5; // M1:M4 now point to location 10

M6 = M7  = M8  = M9  = M10; // M6:M9 now point to location 10


*M5  = *M10;  //  This does nothing, since they already point to the same location

*M10   = 120; //  All values point to location 10, which now holds the value 120
```

The resulting diagram here is:

```
1 <-
2 <-
3 <-
4 <-
5 <-
6 <-
7 <-
8 <-
9 <-
120 <- M1,M2,M3,M4,M5,M6,M7,M8,M9,M10
```

Comment: thank you very very very  much.  can you please tell me if you have an array of pointers, for example std::vector<int *> , what is the fastest way to make them all to follow one pointer.

Comment: for eample   std::vector<int *>  PointerArray = {M1 , M2, M3 , M4 , M5};

Comment: PointerArray .at(0)   =  M5...   and so on... without  for loop or while loop

Comment: You'll have to do a loop at some point. But, if what you're looking for is the same as my last example, but with arrays, you'd do it with one for loop. In pseudocode that would be: `for each pointer, set point to M10`. Your only have to do that once, since now all pointers point to the same location, and so their value is the always the same.